# What is the meaning of Bran Stark's dreams with a three-eyed raven?

Tags: game-of-thrones

After is come, Bran Stark repeatedly made dreams that include a three-eyed raven :

[image: Three-eyed raven]

What is the meaning of those dreams? Does the three-eyed raven has an universal symbolism that I don't know about?

The show names it the [Three-eyed Raven](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Three-eyed_raven).
The books calls it the [Three-eyed Crow](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Three-eyed_crow).

Comment: Have you read *A Dance With Dragons*? If you have not, then you should read it to answer your question, and an answer here would be a spoiler. If you have read it, you'll need to give more detail about what you don't understand.

Comment: I follow the series on TV, but if the answer lie in *A Dance With Dragons* you could answer the question by using the spoiler tag.

Comment: This is a premature question on your part. Just keep reading, as GRRM would say, it will become clear.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The meaning (and identity) behind the three-eyed crow is revealed in *A Dance With Dragons*.

Until then, earlier in the series the three-eyed crow represents a mysterious mentor, who can act as some sort of guide for Bran (teaching him how to "fly"), as revealed both by Bran's dreams and Jojen Reed's greendreams.

> In *A Dance with Dragons* Bran and the Reeds reach the three-eyed crow, who is revealed to be a powerful skinchanger and greenseer, who resides underground with a population of remaining Children of the Forest.  He was, at one time, a member of the Night's Watch, but now sits on his underground seat encased by weirwood roots, using his skinchanging and greenseer powers to unknown purposes.  He begins to teach Bran how to use those same powers, opening Bran's "third eye", which is a reference to Bran learning to unlock his greenseer powers.

Out of universe, the ["third eye" or "inner eye"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_eye) is a reference to the [brow chakra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajna), and being able to open the third eye is said to allow great spiritual insight, or even the ability to enter into another's body.

Comment: You beat me! =) I was going to tackle the speculation as to who the three-eyed crow is as well, which in ADwD is not yet explicitly known, but that probably strays from the actual question. Good answer.

Comment: @Josh - And like most things ASOIAF, a 5-page treatise on the history and lineage of said crow wouldn't be hard to produce.

Comment: I would say that the meaning of the three-eyed crow is revealed a lot sooner that ADWD. I believe Bran and Jojen decide to go see him as early as either ACOK or ASOS. Which would imply that he being a person is something that has been revealed.

Comment: @TLP I don't believe it was revealed exactly *what* the three-eyed crow was until they actually arrive in ADWD. Prior to that, all that they know is that they have to "find the three-eyed crow", because the dreams revealed that Bran must.  They certainly didn't learn any of the information in my spoiler until then.

Comment: @Beofett I think it was fairly clear very early that he was a person with powers. He talks with Bran in his coma dreams, and I believe Jojen says that Bran must be trained by someone, and that that someone is the three-eyed crow. It leaves little doubt that s/he is a person. Though of course, as you say, the exact identity is not revealed until they meet him in ADWD. On a related note.. I wonder if it is better to read Dunk & Egg before or after?

Comment: @TLP I think it is *implied* that it is a person with powers, but as I said, it isn't actually *revealed* until they meet him. It could very well have been one of the Children of the Forest (that was one of my pet theories, actually), which, imo, would have been a bit different.  I still need to read Dunk & Egg, so I'm hoping "after" is the better choice!

Comment: @Beofett It contains references that you will love to read about. The stories themselves are so-so, but the people, references and history of Westeros is awesome.