# Is the character Carrie Fisk from The Expanse inspired by Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, inspiration, the-expanse-novels

*Persepolis Rising*, the seventh book of *The Expanse* series, introduces and features a character named **Carrie Fisk**; she is the leader of the

> **Associations of Worlds**, an organization of various human colonies born on planets discovered after the activation of the Ring Network, with the purpose of vouch for those colonies' interests and representativenes in the broader human community.

Do we know if she, or more specifically her name, was inspired by the actress **Carrie Fisher**, that as everyone knows acted as Princess Leia in the *Star Wars* movies? Or maybe simply an homage or a nod to her?

Comment: I can understand the downvotes, even if I would prefer if they come with a comment. But why the "primarily opinion based" close votes? I've explicitly asked if we know about inspirations or intentional homages, I'm not interested in personal opinions. I think that this question is answerable by community standards without having to throw in opinions.

Comment: I've had a quick look about and not found anything concrete that supports or denies your claim - however this reddit thread asks a similar question, and one of the answers suggest that Carrie Fisk could also be a reference to Colonel Fisk from BSG - https://www.reddit.com/r/TheExpanse/comments/80tu45/pr_carrie_fisk_no_spoilers/

Comment: Thank you @Jimmery, I'm not a reddit user and was not aware of that

Comment: No problem.  Personally, I don't understand the hate this question has received, I think it is perfectly legitimate.

Comment: I doubt it. The two characters don't have much in common besides the similarity in the names.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a quick look about and not found anything concrete that supports or denies your claim - however [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheExpanse/comments/80tu45/pr_carrie_fisk_no_spoilers/) asks a similar question, and one of the answers suggest that Carrie Fisk could also be a reference to Colonel Fisk from BSG

> Do we know if she, or more specifically her name, was inspired by the actress Carrie Fisher.

Given the lack of solid information, all I can say is that we do not know.

Comment: @Jimmery probably adding the link and additional info that you included in your comment will give your answer more completeness and more appeal

Comment: @Jimmery take these answers - [link](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/168978/83101) and [link](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/169902/83101) - as examples of accepted and good "we don't know" answers, they provide more details and explainations.